# Acentuação de parâmetro de request em página JSF

Tags: jsf, demoiselle, tomcat

Tenho uma página JSF que recebe como parâmetro, na URL, a mensagem de erro a ser exibida. Ex.: `http://example.com/application_error.jsf?exception=Não+permitido`

Na página, o parâmetro é exibido da seguinte forma:

```
#{param['exception']}
```

No entanto, os caracteres acentuados ficam errados.

Estou usando o framework Demoiselle e o servidor Tomcat 7. Minhas páginas são UTF-8.

A página em questão é a página `application_error`, para a qual o Demoiselle redireciona quando uma `ApplicationException`  é lançada.

Como faço pra corrigir o problema de acentuação sem precisar mudar a codificação de caracteres que estou usando nas minhas páginas?

Comment: Tente fazer o encode da mensagem antes de redirecionar pra tela: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5330104/encoding-url-query-parameters-in-java

Comment: O problema é que é o framework que faz o redirect quando é lançada uma exceção. Quando eu faço o encode da mensagem, alguns caracteres são duplamente codificados. Por exemplo, a mensagem "a b" vira "a+b" e, quando faz o redirect, vira "a%2Bb".

Comment: Entendi... faz o decode por javascript então: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12042592/decoding-url-parameters-with-javascript

Comment: Pode até ser, mas ainda estou procurando uma solução melhor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O tomcat considera toda a requisição como sendo `ISO-8859-1` por padrão "de fábrica".

A solução direta e específica para o tomcat é alterar a configuração do servidor (`server.xml`):

```xml
<Server port="8105" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
...
    <Service name="Catalina">
        <Connector port="8180" URIEncoding="UTF-8" />
        <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">
            <Host name="localhost" appBase="webapps" />
        </Engine>
    </Service>
....
</Server>
```

Entretanto, não considero essa solução ideal porque quando você precisar fazer o *deploy* de sua aplicação num ambiente controlado por terceiros provavelmente não terá acesso a essa alteração.

Uma solução que pode ser implementada na própria aplicação se divide (pelo menos) em: ajustar o *encoding* no corpo das requisições, nos parâmetros e nos cabeçalhos.

Para resolver o problema para dados no corpo da requisição, eu costumo adicionar um filtro à aplicação no `web.xml` que força o encoding ser de um determinado tipo. Em um projeto onde uso Spring, o seguinte trecho resolve o problema:

```xml
<filter>
    <filter-name>encoding-filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>encoding-filter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Caso não use o Spring, você pode usar o [código da biblioteca apache](http://www.javafaq.nu/java-example-code-235.html) e colocar a classe no seu próprio projeto.

Para os dados em cabeçalhos ou parâmetros, podemos encapsular o `HttpServletRequest` através de um filtro. Fiz a implementação abaixo, mas não tenho uma aplicação em mãos para testar, então qualquer problema me dê um *feedback*:

```java
public class ParametersEncodingFilter implements Filter {

    private String charset = "UTF-8";

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
        String charsetParam = filterConfig.getInitParameter("charset");
        if (charsetParam != null && !charsetParam.isEmpty()) {
            this.charset = charsetParam;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        chain.doFilter(new FilteredRequest(charset, request), response);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        //nothing to clean up
    }

    final private static class FilteredRequest extends HttpServletRequestWrapper {

        public FilteredRequest(String charset, ServletRequest request) {
            super((HttpServletRequest)request);

            //convert encoding params
            Map<String, String[]> originalParams = super.getParameterMap();
            for(Object key : originalParams.keySet()) {

                String[] entry = originalParams.get(key);
                for (int i = 0; i < entry.length; i++) {

                    try {
                        entry[i] = new String(entry[i].getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), charset);
                    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                        return; //if can't convert one, it cannot convert any of them
                    }

                }

            }

        }        

    }

}
```

Nota: esta implementação considera que o filtro possui um parâmetro com o encoding desejado, como na configuração do filtro do Spring mais acima.

E um último comentário: se for possível codificar os parâmetros da URL, por exemplo `N%C3%A3o%2Bpermitido` ao invés de `Não+Permitido`, talvez resolvesse o problema específico do parâmetro sem implementações adicionais.

Comment: Já uso essa solução para corrigir um problema de acentuação na submissão de forms, mas por alguma razão ela não funcionou para o meu problema atual de exibição de parâmetros de requisição.

Comment: @rodrigorgs, já tentou trocar de browser? Em qual você está testando?

Comment: Tentei no Chrome e no Firefox, usando Ubuntu; os demais caracteres acentuados na página aparecem ok, o problema é só com o que vem do `param`.

Comment: Entendo, acho o filtro que postei não afeta os headers, apenas os o corpo da requisição. Creio que uma solução efetiva mais genérica seria criar um filtro com um HttpServletRequestWrapper que fizesse essa conversão que você faz no Converter. Ou, como diz a [documentação do Tomcat](http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/CharacterEncoding#Q2), altera a configuração geral do servidor. Infelizmente mexer nisso é complicado pois sua aplicação pode apresentar problemas em diferentes ambientes.

Comment: essa solução do HttpServletRequestWrapper parece promissora. O que acha de desenvolver essa solução na sua resposta?

Comment: @rodrigorgs Feito.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11946/discussion-between-rodrigorgs-and-utluiz)

Answer (score 1):

Pelo que entendi, o Tomcat decodifica parâmetros GET usando ISO-8859-1. Como não tenho acesso à configuração do servidor, adotei uma solução de contorno. Criei um converter para transformar em UTF-8:

```java
@Named
public class EncodingConverter implements Converter {

  @Override
  public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component,
      String value) {
    return null;
  }

  @Override
  public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
    String result = null;

    if (value != null) {
      String string = (String)value;
      Charset toCharset = Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1");
      Charset fromCharset = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
      result = new String(string.getBytes(toCharset), fromCharset);
    }

    return result;
  }
}
```

Ao exibir o valor na página xhtml, passo pelo converter.

```xml
<h:outputText value="#{param['exception']}" converter="#{encodingConverter}" />
```