# Diferença de caracter enconding Charset difference using JPA but not with prepared statement

Tags: java, oracle, jpa, spring, codificação-de-caracteres

Eu tenho uma aplicação usando spring boot + oracle (via tomcat datasource). 
Usando spring-data, uma consulta simples em uma tabela retorna caracteres com problema de encoding.

Esta mesma aplicação, em uma situação muito específica, eu crio uma conexão direta (sem datasource) com JDBC e executo uma consulta na mesma tabela. Mas, neste caso, não há problema com o encoding.

Obs .: Antes eu pensei que seria apenas um problema com o front-end (algum componente JS), mas verificando o response HTTP pelo browser, os dados já estão com problema no primeiro caso, mas não no segundo.

Desculpe se esta é uma questão duplicada, mas não consegui encontrar algo semelhante. Eu sei que há um monte de questões com oracle+java+charset, mas o meu problema se difere dos outros que eu encontrei.

Comment: Olá, Igor. Você configurou o Spring Boot ou algum filter na sua aplicação para forçar o encoding `UTF-8` na aplicação? Tem alguma configuração de encoding na URL sua conexão com o banco? Consegue depurar a aplicação e ver se os dados são recuperados já com problemas? Verifique também se a requisição HTTP tem na resposta algum encoding definido. Infelizmente há diversas variáveis que precisam ser analisadas. Se puder verificar os pontos acima e adicionar mais informações na sua pergunta, poderemos ajudar mais.

Comment: @utluiz, muito obrigado pela resposta. Não configurei nada específico no Spring nem na URL de conexão. Como ocorre em um ambiente externo do cliente, ainda não depurei, mas vai ser minha proxima tentativa. Quanto a HTTP, verificando pelo response no browser (F12 - chrome), o json já retorna com erro em requisições via datasource e normal em requisições via jdbc.

Comment: Coloquei algumas dicas de verificação do encoding na resposta porque é um problema comum. Se encontrar a causa, adicione uma resposta você mesmo.

Answer (score 0):

## Identificando problemas de codificação numa aplicação Java Web

Há várias hipóteses que só podem ser validadas com a devida verificação no sistema.

1. Os dados já estão corrompidos no banco. Neste caso o problema é na recepção ou gravação dos dados.

   1. O servidor pode estar decodificando a requisição incorretamente.

      - Verifique se os valores já chegam corrompidos no seu *controller*, *servlet*, *action*, etc.
      - Verifique se o `enctype` do formulário na página que envia os dados está correto.
      - Verifique se o navegador envia a codificação correta na requisição.
      - Verifique se o servidor de aplicação está configurado com a codificação adequada. Alguns servidores de aplicação precisam que o encoding seja definido antes de ocorrer a decodificação dos valores da requisição, quando você ou o framework usado primeiro acessa esses valores. [Uma estratégia comum é usar um *servlet filter*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/220/227).
   2. Os dados podem ser corrompidos ao serem gravados no banco.

      - Verifique se a tabela do banco de dados possui a codificação correta. Bancos como MySQL devem usar por padrão o encoding`utf8_general_ci` ou similar.
      - Verifique na documentação do *driver* do banco de dados se nas configurações da conexão com o banco, tal como a URL de conexão, já existe ou é necessário adicionar alguma configuração para definir o *encoding*.
2. Os dados estão corretos no banco, mas chegam corrompidos no Java. Neste caso é uma má configuração da conexão com o banco.

   - Verifique as configurações conforme o item anterior sobre conexão com o banco.
3. Os dados são lidos corretamente no Java, mas chegam corrompidos no cliente. Neste caso pode ser que o browser esteja decodificando a resposta da requisição com um encoding diferente da que o servidor usou para escrever a resposta.

   - Verifique se o servidor envia a codificação correta no cabeçalho da resposta. Veja o item anterior sobre usar um *servlet filter*.
   - Verifique se o servidor realmente codifica a resposta correta. Veja o item anterior sobre usar um *servlet filter*.
   - Verifique se há uma tag `<meta>` definindo um *encoding* diferente daquele do cabeçalho HTTP.